# Fetch data from mysql via PHP, then group rows with similar column values and count

Tags: php, mysql, row, fetch

I basically have this program which fetches orders from a database. My problem is I need to make a report in such a way that the script will get rows with the same column value then count them and display them.

Say Table 'orders'

```
salesorder family product
1111111    pi_gx  af000
1111111    pi_gx  af000
1111112    sfng   af111
1111113    pi_gx  af000
```

will display in my php page

```
sales order   family  qty   product
1111111       pi_gx   2     af000
1111112       sfng    1     af111
1111113       pi_gx   1     af000
```

It counts the quantity of row of the said sales order and displays the quantity, at the same time displays only a single copy of that sales order in my page.

Here's the code:

```
<body class="printable"><h1 align="center">New Orders Dropped for Product Integration 1X</h1>
<table align="center" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td class="labels">Prepared: </td>
<td class="boxed"><?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");$today = date("d/m/y H:i");echo $today; ?></td>
    <td class="divider">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="labels">Time Coverage:  </td>
    <td class="boxed">12:00 to 2:00</td>
    <td class="divider">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="labels">BirthStamp: </td>
    <td class="boxed">5/21/2012</td>
    <td class="divider">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="labels">Saved: </td>
    <td class="boxed"><?php echo $today; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="labels">Prepared by (Production): </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="preparer" id="preparer" class="boxedPrepared" /></td>
    <td class="divider"></td>
    <td class="labels">Recorded by (Store): </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="recorder" id="recorded" class="boxedPrepared" /></td>
    <td class="divider"></td>
    <td class="labels">Recorded: </td>
    <td class="boxed" colspan="3"><?php echo $today; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("store") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM report ORDER BY salesorder AND masterproduct ASC") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
    echo "<center><b>No ORDER/S in Queue</b></center>";
} else {
    echo "
    <table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" align=\"center\" class=\"data\">
              <tr>
                <td class=\"dataHeader\">Sales Order</td>
                <td class=\"dataHeader\">Sales Order Code</td>
                <td class=\"dataHeader\">Family</td>
                <td class=\"dataHeader\">Product Code</td>
                <td class=\"dataHeader\">Quantity</td>
                <td class=\"dataHeader\">Birth Stamp</td>
                <td class=\"dataHeader\">Due Date</td>
              </tr>
    ";
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "
              <tr>
                <td class=\"data\">".$result['salesorder']."</td>
                <td class=\"data\"><span class=\"title\">*".$result['salesorder']."*</span><br />".$result['salesorder']."</td>
                <td class=\"data\">".$result['family']."</td>
                <td class=\"data\"><span class=\"title\">*".$result['masterproduct']."*</span><br />".$result['masterproduct']."</td>
                <td class=\"data\">";
                //need to echo the value here                   
                echo "</td>
                <td class=\"data\">".$result['birthstamp']."</td>
                <td class=\"data\"><span class=\"title\">*".$result['duedate']."*</span><br />".$result['duedate']."</td>
              </tr>

        ";  
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Relational databases were created to do this.  I would suggest reading over the `aggregate functions` that mysql supports: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand this much because I'm still a noob. How do I do it?

Comment: In that case I would suggest reading up on what mySQL can do with aggregate functions, joins, and subqueries.  I'm sure you can find some good stuff yourself, but http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php should start you off.

Comment: Sorry, still cannot get it. Can you please tell me what I need to do with my code? I would very much appreciate the help. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT salesorder, family, product, COUNT() AS qty FROM orders 
       GROUP BY salesorder;
```

EDIT: OK, try this on for size:

```
SELECT r.*, t.qty FROM report r LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT salesorder, COUNT() AS qty FROM orders 
         GROUP BY salesorder) t
      ON t.salesorder=r.salesorder
    ORDER BY r.salesorder AND r.masterproduct ASC
```

Comment: Heh, said to myself "I'll just edit in that fix and then view that that comment was".  Nice catch, even if I did fix it before reading it :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, however, the problem is i need to insert it inside another query. Please see my edit above.

Comment: You can totally subquery it like that, no problem.  (I see no edit yet though)

Comment: Hi @zebediah49, Sorry my edit was late. I basically need to do it with the above code, i put in a comment where the quantity should be made. also i am not really sure if my first query is correct for this situation

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yet another wonderful feature of relational databases: the `JOIN` :D.  If you're not familiar with, that will select everything from report, and then glue on the quantities pulled from the subquery, using the salesorder identities to match them up.

Comment: @zebediah49, tried your query with size, shows this " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS qty FROM orders GROUP BY salesorder) t ON t.salesorder=r.salesorder ORDER B' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT() AS qty, sales_order, family, products 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY sales_order
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Thank you guys for helping. I changed my sql query to this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT salesorder, masterproduct, family, birthstamp, duedate, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM report WHERE family = '$family' AND birthstamp BETWEEN '$startDT' AND '$endDT' GROUP BY salesorder, masterproduct, family, duedate  ");
```

and it worked fine!